.NET Core 6.0 Blazor App stopped running on Linux
On a Linux system where a Blazor Application was previously working has mysteriously stopped working and there are no errors or clues as to why.
In the directory of the .dll's where the executable lives, writing this command hangs:
./App --urls http://0.0.0.0:5000 (as it has always been working)
There is no output.  When going to the site it gives me a 500 internal server error.  No logs are ever written because I figured out that the application runs all the way up to the point in the Program.cs file to app.Run(), but that's where it stops.  Because the rest of the app doesn't run, no logs are every persisted.
When I look at the apache error logs configured, it only gives me a simple "500 error" for the access logs.  The error logs are silent.
I really don't know what happened, and I'm not sure as to what the problem is if the application itself does not run anymore since there's nothing to go off of to figure out why it's hanging at app.Run().
I've tried compiling the app on both Mac and Windows on .NET 6 but both act the same.
How can I troubleshoot such a problem?
